# When is a graph a triangulation of a polygon?

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry

This question came up in an undergraduate math club meeting yesterday.

As we know, a graph is *planar* if it can be embedded in the plane with no edges crossing.  A famous necessary and sufficient combinatorial condition for a graph to be planar is Kuratowski's theorem: a graph $G$ is planar iff it does not contain a subdivision of the complete graph $K_5$ or the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$.

Now consider a polygon $P$ in the plane (a finite sequence of vertices successively joined by non-crossing line segments).  I do not require that $P$ be convex.  A *triangulation* of $P$ consists of the original polygon $P$ together with additional non-crossing line segments joining vertices of $P$, such that the interior of $P$ is partitioned into triangles.  (So you are not allowed to add internal vertices.  I am not sure if this is exactly the usual definition of "triangulation".)  You can view this triangulation as a graph, using the vertices of the original polygon, and all the original and added line segments as edges.

Here is a crude drawing.  The green points are the vertices, the black lines are the original polygon, the red lines are the added segments of the triangulation.

[image]

Let me say an (abstract) finite graph $G$ is a *polygon triangulation* if there exists a polygon $P$ and a triangulation of $P$ which, as a graph, is isomorphic to $G$.

> Given a finite graph $G$, is there a necessary and sufficient *combinatorial* condition for $G$ to be a polygon triangulation? (Perhaps analogous to Kuratowski?)

We came up with some necessary conditions:

- $G$ must be **planar**, obviously.  So by Kuratowski it may not contain a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.
- $G$ must be **connected**, also obvious.
- $G$ must be **3-colorable**.  (So not every planar graph is a polygon triangulation; in particular, $K_4$ is not a polygon triangulation.)  This much seems to be well known.

(Here is a sketch of a proof for 3-colorability. Induct on the number $n$ of vertices of $G$.  The base case $n=3$ is trivial.  For the inductive step, let $G$ be a polygon triangulation with $n$ vertices.  Fix an embedding of $G$ which is a polygon triangulation.  Consider the dual graph $G'$ of $G$, excluding the outside face.  $G'$ must be acyclic, because a cycle in $G'$ would make a loop inside $P$ that encloses a vertex of $P$, contradicting the simply-connectedness of $P$.  So $G'$ contains a leaf; this corresponds to a triangular face of $G$ with two exterior edges $e_1, e_2$.  Let $v$ be the vertex between those edges; it cannot be incident on any other edges, so $v$ has degree 2.  By the inductive hypothesis we can properly 3-color $G -v$.  But since $v$ has degree 2 we can color $v$ also, so $G$ is 3-colorable.)

But we didn't discover a necessary and sufficient condition.

(Note: This is not my field so it's very likely that I'm misusing terminology or ignorant of well-known facts.  Please feel free to enlighten me!)

Comment: Is it enough to add a condition on the number of edges?

Comment: It is likely easier (probably a lot easier because the Euler characteristic applies) to determine when a graph is a total (interior and exterior) triangulation of a polygon.

Comment: If you can speak about the dual graph, then it seems you have a particular embedding (or homotopy class of embeddings) into the plane in mind -- that would seem to make it easy to say that it consists of triangles and all vertices border the infinite face?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I don't want to assume that an embedding of $G$ is given.  I guess I should take that condition out.  Maybe it is true that for any planar embedding of $G$, the dual graph is a tree - but I'm not sure that I can prove it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Or, is the question, does there exist a planar embedding which is the triangulation of a polygon?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Yes, that is the question.

Comment: You might also need a condition that the intersections of the neighbor sets of two vertices connected by an edge has a third vertex in common.

Comment: Are you asking about conditions for a graph to be a [maximal planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Maximal_planar_graphs)?

Comment: @Casteels: I don't think so, because $K_4$ is maximal planar (trivially), but not a polygon triangulation in my sense.  One of the vertices has to go in the middle of the polygon, which I don't allow.

Comment: @Casteels It is not the same as a maximal planar graph because the outer face need not be a triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard name for the graphs you describe are *[maximal outerplanar graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outerplanar_graph#Related_families_of_graphs)*.

As noted on the linked-to Wikipedia page, a graph is outerplanar if and only if it has no $K_4$ or $K_{2,3}$ minor, and an outerplanar graph is maximal if and only if it has $2n-3$ edges, where $n$ is the number of vertices.